# PHP update table data based on other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

I am trying to create a cron job that will select the sum of points from a transaction table.

Based on the Sum of the points and the employee id I must update the total point table.
I want to make sure that I am using the best method and that this will work.

```
 <?php

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
        echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT ID, SUM(POINTS) as Points, FROM Transactions WHERE Status = 1 Group By ID";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
        exit;
    }


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  

    mysql_query("UPDATE Totals SET Points=" + $row["Points"] + "WHERE ID=" +  $row["id"]);

    }


    mysql_free_result($result);

    ?>
```

Comment: I am curious why you wouldn't just make a trigger on the table for this kind of thing. Are these tables not in the same database?

Comment: You may be hurting Pandas. [Please read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still join tables (*and subqueries*) on `UPDATE` statements. Try this one,

```
UPDATE Totals a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, SUM(POINTS) as Points, 
            FROM Transactions 
            WHERE Status = 1 
            Group By ID
        ) b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
SET a.Points = b.Points
```

Hope this helps.

example of using **[PDO Extension (Code Snippet)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**.

```
<?php

$query = "UPDATE Totals a 
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT ID, SUM(POINTS) as Points, 
                FROM Transactions 
                WHERE Status = ? 
                Group By ID
            ) b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
    SET a.Points = b.Points";

$iStatus = 1;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $iStatus);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

**[PDO Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** 
**[PDO PreparedStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**

Comment: hey one more thing, use PDO or MySQLI Extension when using PHP. `mysql_*` are already depreciated.

Comment: do you by any chance know how i would implement PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just test the script out out before you run it via a cron job? I can't spot anything that's wrong with the syntax; but then again, I only gave it a quick glance and I don't know what your table structure is like.

If you're looking for the BEST way to do things, then you should looking into using mysqli or PDO instead of the mysql functions. That way, you can make use of prepared statements, which won't be as taxing on your DBMS if you're planning on running multiple queries inside a loop. Prepared statements don't require you to make separate round trips to the server, whereas the old mysql functions do.

Comment: thats what i am trying to figure out how would i do the same thing i did in a better method such as using PDO